# How to make cursor shrink and grow?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm want to take image and insert it to cursor and on mouse scroll the cursor will shrink or grow.

I try to do it by convert image to base64 and then to cursor, i just test it without scroll and it always make black square cursor.

```
    img64 = new Image();
    img64.src = './assets/tools/pencil.png';
    var cnva64 = document.createElement('canvas');
    cnva64.height = img64.naturalHeight;
    cnva64.width = img64.naturalWidth;
    var ctx64 = cnva64.getContext('2d');

    ctx64.drawImage(img64, 0, 0, cnva64.width, cnva64.height);
    var base64String = cnva64.toDataURL();
    Board.canvas.style.cursor = `url(${base64String}), auto`;
```

Edit

if i'm doing it like this it's work but it isn't take the size of it

```
    img = new Image();
    img.src = './assets/tools/cursor/pencil.png';
    img.style.width = "58px";
    img.style.height = "38px";

    Board.canvas.style.cursor = `url(${img64.src}), auto`;
```

Comment: when i convert it to base64 the and insert it cursor the image is black square and not the actual image, idk why

Comment: if i doing it like this it's work
```
img = new Image();
    img.src = './assets/tools/cursor/pencil.png';
    img.style.width = "58px";
    img.style.height = "38px";
     
    Board.canvas.style.cursor = `url(${img64.src}), auto`;
```


but it isn't take the size of it

Comment: Setting image's CSS height/width has an effect on image's presentation only, when it is appended to a page as an image element. You need a different image for all the stages of scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manged to do what i wanted but then i notified by chrome

> Remove cursors greater than 32x32 device-independent pixels intersecting native UI

```
window.addEventListener('load', () =>{


    Board = new CanvasBoard()

    Board.canvas.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
        let linesize = document.getElementById("LineSizePicker");
        let add = (e.deltaY/100)*-1
        if(parseInt(linesize.value)+add<=88 && parseInt(linesize.value)+add>0){
            linesize.value = parseInt(linesize.value)+add;
            Board.ChangeLineSize(linesize.value);
        }
    });
})



class CanvasBoard{
    constructor(){
        this.canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.Mode = "Pencil";

        let img = document.getElementById(`${this.Mode}IMG`)
        let CursorBae64 = this.ToBase64(img,28)
        this.canvas.style.cursor = `url(${CursorBae64}), auto`
    }
    ToBase64(img64,Size){
        img64.Height = Size;
        img64.width = Size;
        let Canvas64 = document.createElement('canvas');
        Canvas64.height = img64.Height;
        Canvas64.width = img64.width;
        let ctx64 = Canvas64.getContext('2d');
        ctx64.drawImage(img64, 0, 0, Canvas64.width, Canvas64.height);
        let Base64 = Canvas64.toDataURL();
        return B64
    }
    ChangeLineSize(Size){
        let img64 = document.getElementById(`${this.Mode}IMG`)
        img64.src = document.getElementById(`Old${this.Mode}IMG`).src
        if(Size>10 && Size<40){
            let base64 = this.ToBase64(img64,Size);
            img64.src = base64;
            this.canvas.style.cursor = `url(${img64.src}) 0 -${Size}, auto`
        }
        this.lineThickness = Size
    }
}
```